# Dynamic worksheet name inside vba according to combo box selection

Tags: vba, excel

thanks in advance for your time.
I need to write in cell P3 in the activesheet, the value that is at cell P3 from the worksheet that I selected in the combo box "cbplan" in a Userform (which has a list of worksheet names that are in my workbook).

I tried that with no success:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wsb As Worksheet
Set wsb = cbplan.Value
ActiveSheet.Range("P3") = wsb.Range("P3").Value

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Please, someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the error I think you are, just change the line where you `set wsb`

```
 Set wsb = Sheets(cbplan.Value)
```

Comment: That's it! And you can shorten it all down to: ActiveSheet.Range("P3").Value = Sheets(cbplan.Value).Range("P3").Value

Comment: @user3598756 is correct unless you plan to use wsb elsewhere, it's just easier not to have to declare a variable at all if you aren't going to use it again.